# pentaho modified java script value

Tags: java, pentaho, kettle

I have an xml file that I'm converting to CSV that contains a string, which when present indicates a new record of data. I want to create a counter (I think this is best done with modified java script value) to increment each time the value is present.

Currently I'm using this code in modified javascript value:

```
var xmlRecordNum;
xmlRecordNum = 0;

if (xml_data_name == "NewRow"){
xmlRecordNum++;
}
```

However, xmlRecordNum always resets to 0.

```
thing, xml_data_name, xmlRecordNum
t1,NewRow,1
t2,x1,0
t3,x2,0
t4,NewRow,1
t4,x4,0
```

What I want to see is:

```
t1,NewRow,1
t2,x1,1
t3,x2,1
t4,NewRow,2
t4,x4,2
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to preserve values across rows?

var xmlRecordNum;
if ( xmlRecordNum==null ) { xmlRecordNum = 0 };

OR use a start script (right click the tab) and just put the var xmlRecordNum=0 code in that.  (Slightly cleaner solution)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!